# OpenCV cv::Mat release for free Memory

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-processing

I try to release from memory an image cv::Mat but with poor results.
Before the creation of the image, Memory is 20,3 MB

```
cv::Mat image = [self cvMatWithImage:originalUIImage];
```

Now Memory is 54,3 MB..and in next line, for testing, i release the cv::Mat

```
image.release();
```

I see that memory is 37,2 MB, why?

Method cvMatWithImage :

```
- (cv::Mat)cvMatWithImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGImageGetColorSpace(image.CGImage);
    CGFloat cols = image.size.width;
    CGFloat rows = image.size.height;

    cv::Mat cvMat(rows, cols, CV_8UC4); // 8 bits per component, 4 channels

    CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(cvMat.data,                 // Pointer to backing data
                                                    cols,                       // Width of bitmap
                                                    rows,                       // Height of bitmap
                                                    8,                          // Bits per component
                                                    cvMat.step[0],              // Bytes per row
                                                    colorSpace,                 // Colorspace
                                                    kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast |
                                                    kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault); // Bitmap info flags

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, cols, rows), image.CGImage);
    CGContextRelease(contextRef);

    return cvMat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the entire problem, but you probably want to use CV_8UC3 instead of CV_8UC4, since kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast has only 3 channels.